# How do I implement Send Bird push notification in React Native

Tags: react-native, sendbird

I am using sendbird for developing a message application in React Native. The official documentation covers push notification for Android and iOS only.

How do I implement it in React Native?

Comment: did you ever find out how to do it? I'm trying to do it in Cordova and it doesn't seem to offer that in their API's the same way they do for all other platforms.